# Difference between "non-decreasing" and "increasing"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

> In this section, we use a similar technique to solve the sorting
> problem, that is, starting with an unordered array of elements and rearranging them
> into **non-decreasing** order.

This line is taken from a coding textbook where they are basically discussing sorting algorithms. Sorting algorithms either sort in an increasing order or a decreasing order depending on the input type.

Does the word *non-decreasing* here mean same as that of *increasing*? Is there any particular situation where they have different meanings? Also, can these two words be used interchangeably in a context?

Comment: The answer given is correct.  However, there is no doubt that a lot of the time (certainly in less technical speech) "increasing order" means the same thing as "non-decreasing order".  If someone asked me to sort 1, 2, 3, 4, 4 into increasing order, I would simply sort them into non-decreasing order.  I wouldn't say "oh, no, that's impossible".

Answer (score 3):

No, the difference is behavior at the limit.

- Non-decreasing includes **both** increasing and level ordering; e.g., 1, 2, 3, 3, 4.
- Increasing excludes steady-state, so in the previous example, "3, 3" is not allowed.

Compare with similar math operators, greater-than (>) vs. greater=than-or-equal-to (>=).